# Queries to retrieve data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables.

[image]

a. salesperson(SSN, lName, startYear, deptNo)

b. trip(tripID, SSN, fromCity, toCity, departureDate, returnDate)

c. expense(tripID, accountNumber, amount)

The primary keys for each table are. SSN for the Salesperson table. TripId for the Trip table, and tripID and account number for the Expense table.

The foreign keys for each table are. deptNo for the Salesperson table. SSN in the Trip table, and tripID in the Expense Table

---

What I am trying to do:

1) Find the tripID, SSN, fromCity, tocity, departureDate, returnDate and amount for trips that exceed $2000 in expenses.

2) Find the SSN for Sales Representatives that took trips to ‘CHICAGO’.

3) Find the total trip expenses incurred by the salesman with SSN = ‘123-45-6789’.

I did not create any of this, it is a practice assignment from school, thank you very much for the help and please don't use very technical language.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT tripID,SSN,fromCity,tocity,departureDate,returnDate
FROM
(SELECT Trip.tripID, Trip.SSN, Trip.fromCity, Trip.tocity, Trip.departureDate, Trip.returnDate,sum(Expense.amount) total
FROM Trip left join Expense
ON Trip.tripID = Expense.tripID
GROUP BY Trip.tripID) data
WHERE data.total>2000
```

2.

```
SELECT distinct SSN 
FROM Trip 
WHERE fromCity='Chicago'
```

3.

```
SELECT sum(Expense.amount) total
    FROM Trip left join Expense
    ON Trip.tripID = Expense.tripID
GROUP BY Trip.SSN = '123456789'
```

You have to check these by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's all great except for #1 does not show the 'amount' column, sum(Expense.amount) when running the query

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking for the full solution to your assignment. StackOverflow is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site. You won't, or at least you shouldn't, get any help unless you show that you have at least attempted to write the queries yourself. People will be happy to help fix specific issues if you are having trouble getting a query you have written to work as it should.

I suggest you try this tutorial, paying particular attention to sections 1, 3, 4, 5, 11, 8, 17 & 18 :

[25 Essential MySQL Select Command Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/mysql-select-command/)

Edited to add: I suggest you tackle the second query first as it is the simplest. If you can get that one working you should be able to expand your understanding in order to implement the other two.

Comment: Thank you and I understand where I went wrong with this post. These are the 3/15 queries I had trouble with so it wasn't my whole assignment. I just needed some guidance or pointing in the right direction of how the query should look or what commands should be used. Thanks for the help anyway